# Printf linkedList in C Errors

Tags: c, linked-list, printf

I am trying to read data from file. Every line of the file consists of : string1 string2 float
In example: A1 A2 5.22
I am trying to printf to the screen the value of first element of linked list, but every time I get errors:

in "program.c" file -
error: request for member "weight" in something not a structure or union

```
printf("%f", data -> weight);
```

or 
in "main.c" file -
 error : dereferencing pointer to incompatible type

```
printf("%f\n", data ->weight);
```

Maybe someone could help me with an output of member data to the screen. Where could be the problem and how could I correct it? Because I tried reading other answers on this topic, trying different variations, but nothing worked out for "data" member.

**Edited** : The problems I have solved by changing :
typedef struct node* node;
to
typedef struct node node;

But the error with "main.c":
error : dereferencing pointer to incompatible type
Still remains. Maybe someone has any ideas how could I correct my code?

Edited code:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "program.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){
    if(argc != 3){return 0;}
    node* data;
    data = getData(argv ,&data);
    printf("%f \n", data -> weight); //here second mentioned error appears

return 0;
}
```

program.h

```
#ifndef program_h
#define program_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "program.h"

typedef struct node node;  

node* getData (char* argv[], node** data);

#endif
```

program.c

```
#include "program.h"

struct node                                          
{   
    char* from;
    char* to;
    float weight;
    struct node *next;
};

node* getData (char* argv[], node** data){

    node* elem; 
    node* lastElem;

    FILE *in=fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (in == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file !\n");
        exit(1);
    } 

    char* string1 = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    char* string2 = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));;
    float dataW; // dataWeigth

    fscanf(in, "%s" ,string1);
    fscanf(in, "%s" ,string2);
    lastElem = malloc( sizeof(struct node));
    lastElem -> next = NULL;
    lastElem -> from = string1;
    *data = lastElem;
    printf("%f",(*data)->weight); 


    if(!feof(in)){
        fscanf(in, "%f%*[^\n]" ,&dataW);
        lastElem -> to = string2;
        lastElem -> weight = dataW;
        while (!feof(in)) 
         {
            fscanf(in, "%s" ,string1);
            fscanf(in, "%s" ,string2);
            fscanf(in, "%f%*[^\n]" ,&dataW);
            elem = malloc( sizeof(struct node));
            elem -> next = NULL;
            elem -> from = string1;
            elem -> to = string2;
            elem -> weight = dataW;
            lastElem -> next = elem;
            lastElem = elem;
         }
    }
    fclose(in);
 return *data; 

}
```

Comment: 1. main.c doesn't see the definition of the struct
2. node* is struct node**, which is why you can't dereference it like that.

Comment: @user3109672 I don't understand why, because i thought that I'm passing an address of "data" to the function, so main.c should see the definition...

Comment: `typedef struct node* node;` - this is bad. Either just typedef the name: `typedef struct node node;` or prefix the pointer with `p`, which is a common convention: `typedef struct node* pNode;`

Comment: @szczurcio Thank you, it has actually helped, but the error with main.c still remains. I have edited my code. Maybe you have some ideas about this one error?

Comment: You could use `fscanf()` & `sscanf()` also in taking input from file, is it not much easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
struct node                                          
{   
    char* from;
    char* to;
    float weight;
    struct node *next;
};
```

to

```
typedef struct                                          
{   
    char* from;
    char* to;
    float weight;
    struct node *next;
} node;
```

Move that to `program.h`, and don't include `program.h` in itself - it makes no sense. Instead, include it in both `main.c` and `program.c`.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I'm Unable to see program.c linked up anywhere in main.c or program.h

As it should to there so as to execute the Structure.
.
.
And..
No where you defined "data" as a structure.
As it should be a

```
struct node* data;
```

Or

```
node* data;
```

Calling anything in a function can't make that thing a structure..